# serialize/deserialize List<T> to JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization, generic-list

I want to be able to serialize/deserialize a generic list what I so far is this

```
    public static string ToJson(this object obj, int recursionDepth = 100) 
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        serializer.RecursionLimit = recursionDepth;
        return serializer.Serialize(obj);
    }

    public static List<T> ToListObject<T>(this string obj, int recursionDepth = 100)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        serializer.RecursionLimit = recursionDepth;
        List<T> returnList = serializer.Deserialize<List<T>>(obj);
        return returnList;
    }
```

I also tried `(List<T>)serializer.DeserializeObject(obj)`

With the `Deserialize` it deserializes wrong (to an empty `List<T>` object) and with `DeserializeObject` it throws an error saying 'Could not deserialize the given string into an array of T'. And I wont be able to use the IOStream :( Would really appriciate any insight.

UPDATE: Even the basic serialization/deserialization works, it was just not my day when I posted this. :)

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx) article?

Comment: What is the JSON string that you're trying to deserialize? And what is the type T that you're passing to the ToListObject method?

Comment: Wont work for me as its using a MemoryStream (reading back from it, so it wont be available over a period of time) and I wont be able to use IOStream.

Comment: WCarlosfigueira: T is the generic class name, can be any defined class

Comment: Have you considered creating a [JavaScriptConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.aspx)?

Comment: If you are looking for another tool for JSON serialization you might want to try [JSON.Net][1].


  [1]: http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this on for size:

```
public static T ToObject<T>(this string obj, int recursionDepth = 100)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    serializer.RecursionLimit = recursionDepth;
    return serializer.Deserialize<T>(obj);
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
mystring.ToObject<List<MyClass>>();
```