# serialize to stream or not

Tags: c#

i found two different examples of how to serialize data. One was using a stream and the other not?

```
stream1.Position = 0;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream1);
Console.Write("JSON form of Person object: ");
Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx)

```
   public static string ToJson(this object obj, int recursionDepth = 100)  
    { 
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
        serializer.RecursionLimit = recursionDepth; 
        return serializer.Serialize(obj); 
    } 

    public static List<T> ToListObject<T>(this string obj, int recursionDepth = 100) 
    { 
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
        serializer.RecursionLimit = recursionDepth; 
        List<T> returnList = serializer.Deserialize<List<T>>(obj); 
        return returnList; 
    }
```

[From StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145906/serialize-deserialize-listt-to-json)

Why would you use Stream as an added step?

Comment: You use what you need to get the job done.

Comment: @Boo's answer is incomplete; You use what you need to get the job done as well as you can justify.

Comment: I should like to point out that the StackOverflow Example is doing 2 different things.  One of them turns an object into a stream using `Serialize()` and the other turns a string (or stream, but its just using string directly) into an object using `Deserialize()`.  Stream is a more memory safe way generate the direct representation of an object, filestreams and memorystreams are common for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Stream or reader/writer API may be convenient if you are actually talking to a backed such as a file or network-socket, and the data is large (i.e. you don't want to have to load a huge `string` in memory).

The `string`-based API is more convenient when handling small amounts of data, typical in most AJAX/HTTP scenarios. Note that most serializers **do not have** an API that directly exposes `string` as input/output, but this is such a common scenario with JSON that it has been made easy for you.

One will basically be a convenience wrapper of the other. Which way around is an implementation detail, although I would hope that the primary internal code is stream- or reader/writer- based (to allow for large documents without overhead).

Use whichever is most convenient for your purpose.